# What are all of the available keyword options for Python's logging format strings?

Tags: python, python-logging

I currently have this log format for my application's logger, and would like to know what I can add to it:

`"%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"`

**Where can I find a list of all of these options and what they mean?**

It must be in the official documentation somewhere...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes has all the value you need, you can also add custom attributes.

Answer (score -1):

**Official Documentation:**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

I'm annoyed that I missed this, but in my defense, that document is massive and "LogRecord attributes" is not an intuitive thing to search for when you don't know that they are called that.

Comment: [I mean...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSvGG.png)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I need a nap.